# How to split a decimal number from a String in JAVA

Tags: java

I would like to know the regex for splitting up the decimal number from a string say

`str = "COD Amount = 333.98"`

in the above string value I just need only the decimal values ie `333.98`.

Comment: There are simpler ways other then regex. is it mandatory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's mandatory to use regex? If it's not then you can use:

```
public class Split {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "COD Amount = 333.98";
    String[] array = line.split("=");
    double amount = Double.parseDouble(array[1]);
    System.out.println(amount);
}
}
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

With regex:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Split {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "COD Amount = 333.98";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+= (\\d+\\.\\d+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
}
```

But make sure that all your strings are in the same format: [code] [description] = [number]

(I'm still thinking that the first solution is most appropriate)

**EDIT 2**

Since your input is like this:
`"COD Amount = 333.98, Coverage = $564.000"` (you should provide us the entire format of your lines in the original question)

you can combine the two previous solutions:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Split {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "COD Amount = 333.98, Coverage = $564.000";
    String[] array = line.split(",");

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+= \\$?(\\d+\\.\\d+)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(array[i]);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you validating the string before @Sarathy?
Cause for example:

"COD A231.2mount = 333.98" will produce wrong results on most trivials regex.

This is why splits are fair easier regarding parsing.

Comment: yes i feel regex will do better for my req, bcoz this is how my input values looks like 
COD Amount = 333.98,Coverage = $564.00 
here i need to split the string with "," and again i need to split the  decimal value from already split-ted string.

Comment: @sarathy then you have answered yourself: first use split on the whole line and then use the regex (check my edited answer).

Comment: thanks, this is working fine.... and is there any other way to perform the same action without pattern & matcher? is there any expression that we can put into split() to get the same output. actually i really didn't understand what was regex, but now making sense. so as you said is there any other easy way other than regex  to perform the 2nd split???

Comment: @sarathy Actually `split` receives as a parameter a regex. Use or not a regex in the second split depends on the format of your lines. With the example that you provide I think that maybe possible (Cut the string from the end to the '=' and then check if there is a '$' and then remove it. Check the `substring` method of String class in javadoc.